# Update Canadian (or Australian) currency $ display

Tags: database, configuration, currency

CiviCRM simply shows a $ to represent either Can$ (or australian dollars). This can become confusing when $ currencies mix.

It keeps these symbols in the database. I suspect I can do something like

```
UPDATE civicrm_currency SET symbol = "Can$" WHERE name="CAD";
```

Will this survive updates ? Is there a better way to change this ?

Comment: Sounds like a potentially sane approach. presumably if the currency table gets touched in any upgrade then you might have to rerun your query